# Unable to update database entity using linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

```
var receiptDetailRecord = (from BcchildDetails in _context. BcchildDetails
                        //...
                        select new SubmitReceiptModel
                        {                        
                            ReceiptHeaderId = receiptHeaderRecord. ReceiptHeaderId,
                            FeeComponentId = BcchildDetails. FeeComponentId,
                            //...
                            AmountPaid = BcchildDetails.AmountDue,
                         }
                         );

var receiptAmount = request.ReceiptAmount;
foreach (var record in receiptDetailRecord)
{
    var totalpayable = record.AmountPaid + record.Cgstamount;
    if(receiptAmount >= totalpayable)
    {
        receiptAmount -= (decimal)totalpayable;
        record.AmountPaid = receiptAmount;
    }
    //...
}
    
List<ReceiptDetail> receiptDetailsList = new List<ReceiptDetail>();
```

I'm trying to update `AmountPaid` for every record present in `receiptDetailRecord` based on some calculations. I want to take every record and insert them into `receiptDetailsList`. While debugging the code, as soon as the control comes out of the foreach loop, the records in `receiptDetailRecord` contain the inital values assigned to them which basically means they're not getting updated in the loop.

Comment: `receiptDetailRecord` is a query. It represents the potential to fetch data.  It is not the fetched data yet. Add `.ToList()`, to convert receiptDetailRecord to a `List<SubmitReceiptModel>` and process the fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `receiptDetailRecord` is an IEnumerable, and LINQ queries return results as read-only collections. So you need to get the result as a list by using `ToList()`

```
var receiptDetailRecord = (from BcchildDetails in _context.BcchildDetails
  //...
  select new SubmitReceiptModel {
    ReceiptHeaderId = receiptHeaderRecord.ReceiptHeaderId,
      FeeComponentId = BcchildDetails.FeeComponentId,
      //...
      AmountPaid = BcchildDetails.AmountDue,
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: @TheGreatGatsby what happened?